# jackson converting timestamp to long

Tags: java

I am trying to get all the columns from table and convert it to json.
so trying as below

```
List<Map<String,Object>> map=jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from test");
```

So it it gives list of map having key as the columnName and value as the columnValue.
then I am using `ObjectMapper` to convert the map to as json

```
String tableJson=new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
```

The table is having a column `createdDate` and its type is `timestamp`.
But when the objectmapper is converting the map to json then timestamp is converted to long.

Please help how do I create a json without converting timestamp to long. It can be String date.

Answer (score 1):

Add *jackson-databind* to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

now you can control how to convert the field value, using

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd@HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private Date createdDate;`
```

You can set the date format directly in ObjectMapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSZ");
objectMapper.setDateFormat(df);
String tableJson=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(map);
```

Comment: I don't have any pojo, so how can I add the annotation. I can not pojo also